# top-level marshmallow schema validation

Tags: python, marshmallow

From [Marshmallow#validation](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#validation), I know I can register validators on specific fields in a Schema. If a validator fails, errors in :

```
data, errors = MySchema().load({"some":"data})
```

will include error information for any field which has failed validators :

```
errors
# => some error message for the field that failed
```

My question : Is it possible to validate at the Schema level (rather than at individual field level) and still return an error in the above way?

As an arbitrary example, say I wanted to validate that you tried to `MySchema().load()` n distinct keys.
I currently have a `@pre_load` method which checks the structure of the input and `raise ValidationError('message')` if the data is ill-formed, but I would like to return it as result.errors like field validation does. What are my options?

Comment: `Marshmallow` seems like an interesting library. I was surprised that there wasn't a tag for it so I created one.

Comment: Take a look at the Schema-level validation section of the docs: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending.html#schema-level-validation . It will show you how to use the `@validates_schema` decorator to register schema validators and also how to store errors on specific fields.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [validates_schema](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.decorators.validates_schema) decorator to run validations on whole object:

```
class MySchema(marshmallow.Schema):
    # ...

    @marshmallow.validates_schema(skip_on_field_errors=True)
    def validate_object(self, data):
        if data['foo'] < data['bar']:
            raise marshmallow.ValidationError(
                'Value should not be less than bar',
                ['foo']  # name of field to report error for
            )
```

Although if you want to report multiple errors for different fields independently, Marshmallow at this moment does not support reporting multiple different errors for different fields, and you need to put separate validations into separate methods:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    # ...

    @validates_schema
    def validate_foo(self, data):
        pass

    @validates_schema(skip_on_field_errors=True)
    def validate_bar(self, data):
        pass
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you call `MySchema().validate(data)` instead of `MySchema().load(data)`. Is there a way to get this to work with `validate()`?

Comment: starting from version 3.0.0 the `skip_on_field_errors` defaults to `True`

Comment: @Evan `MySchema().validate(data)` does not raise Validation errors, but returns them, in contrast to loading, which raises.